# Reportico / Sql union query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, reporting, reportico

I got a problem with a query while using Union.

I use the following query to get my result:

```
SELECT substr(directory_vis,locate(":", directory_vis) +1, (locate(">>", directory_vis) - locate(":", directory_vis) -1)) as dossier, count(doc_id) as aantal_documenten
FROM openims_algemeen_document_data
WHERE 1=1
GROUP BY dossier

UNION 

SELECT substr(directory_vis,locate(":", directory_vis) +1, (locate(">>", directory_vis) - locate(":", directory_vis) -1)) as dossier, count(doc_id) as aantal_documenten
FROM postin_document_data
WHERE 1=1
GROUP BY dossier

UNION

SELECT substr(directory_vis,locate(":", directory_vis) +1, (locate(">>", directory_vis) - locate(":", directory_vis) -1)) as dossier, count(doc_id) as aantal_documenten
FROM qualdoc_document_data
WHERE 1=1
GROUP BY dossier
ORDER BY dossier
```

I need to have all the "dossiers" from multiple tables. The problem that I have here is that I get duplicate records. Because the same "dossier" can be in multiple tables.

How can I fix this?

Comment: You know DISTINCT is not a function? It works on the whole row, not just the first select item. (But in your case you can remove it, since you do GROUP BY dossier.)

Comment: Thats true, but you can use it as a function in Reportico (im using a tool to generate reports). Thanks anyway because it indeed can be removed :). But still got the duplicate records, you know something to fix it?

Comment: Perhaps do UNION ALL  the 3 selects (without group by), and then do a GROUP BY on that result?

Comment: Tried it but won't work. I only get 3 records if i dont use group by and the count will be over 500. So I won't get all the dossiers